# Arduino - Code terminates and restarts - SRAM overloading?

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a quadcopter with the Arduino Mega. The project is almost "finished" and ready for a test flight, BUT...

**The code runs up to initializing the SD-card (main file - *test()*-method), then restarts and runs till the end.**

Due to my researches I had a problem with overloading the SRAM (because I used many Strings instead of char-arrays), so I changed nearly all Strings to char arrays. But that didn't fix the error!

---

The error may be in the methods *startup()* and *test()* in the main file, because the code terminates in this segment.
Because the issue may not be in one code section, here is a link to the whole project (all files): *https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6vaoi6gnjgz6ek/MulticopterPro_v0.0.6.rar?dl=0*

---

Here is some of the code:
**Main file - class startup()**

```
void startup(){
  cmd.printMsg(true, msg_startup_start);

  motorControl.batteryDisconnect();

  test();

  // init motor objects
  cmd.printMsg(false, msg_motor_initObjects);
  m1.init();
  m2.init();
  m3.init();
  m4.init();
  cmd.printMsg(true, msg_done);

  // motor speed 0% (=OFF)
  cmd.printMsg(false, msg_motor_speed_off);
  m1.setSpeed(0, false);
  m2.setSpeed(0, false);
  m3.setSpeed(0, false);
  m4.setSpeed(0, false);
  cmd.printMsg(true, msg_done);

  motorControl.batteryConnect();

  // timer (wait or press "O")
  unsigned long timerStarted = millis();
  const byte secondsRemaining_start = 7;
  byte secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining_start;

  cmd.printMsg(true, "[INFO] Press {O} [or wait 7 seconds] to continue");
  while(cmd.readCmd() != 'O'){
    if((millis() - timerStarted) - ((secondsRemaining_start - secondsRemaining) * 1000) >= 1000){
      secondsRemaining--;
      String msg = "[INFO] Press {O} [or wait ";
             msg += secondsRemaining;
      if(secondsRemaining > 1) msg += " seconds] to continue";
      else msg += " second] to continue";

      if(secondsRemaining <= 0) break;

      cmd.printMsg(true, msg);
    }
  }

  // motor speed safe val (=-X%)
  cmd.printMsg(false, msg_motor_speed_safeVal);
  m1.setSpeed(0, true);
  m2.setSpeed(0, true);
  m3.setSpeed(0, true);
  m4.setSpeed(0, true);
  cmd.printMsg(true, msg_done);


  //Werte aus SD auslesen
  //Fehler?

  cmd.printMsg(true, msg_startup_end);
}
```

**Main file - class test()**

```
void test(){
  cmd.printMsg(false, "Initializing SDcard... ");
  if(sdcard.init()){

    cmd.printMsg(true, "done!");


    cmd.printMsg(true, "Initializing variables from SDcard");

    sdcard.openFile("test.txt", 1);
    String fileContent = sdcard.readFile();
    // !!! automatisch: !!!
    String fileContentLines[2] = {{".RC_receiver#receiver_arm_duration#4000"}, {".RC_receiver#receiver_val#1#-100,100"}};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(fileContentLines); i++){

      // RC_receiver
      if(sdcard.getSectionFromText(fileContentLines[i], 1, '#') == "RC_receiver"){
        cmd.printMsg(false, "RC_receiver#");
        if(sdcard.getSectionFromText(fileContentLines[i], 2, '#') == "receiver_val"){
          cmd.printMsg(false, "receiver_val_");
          String channel = sdcard.getSectionFromText(fileContentLines[i], 3, '#');
          cmd.printMsg(false, channel);
          cmd.printMsg(false, ":");

          String values = sdcard.getSectionFromText(fileContentLines[i], 4, '#');
          String value_01 = sdcard.getSectionFromText(values, 1, ',');
          String value_02 = sdcard.getSectionFromText(values, 2, ',');

          //cmd.printMsg(true, strcat(strcat(strcat(strcat("[", value_01), "] - ["), value_02), "]"));

          //cmd.printMsg(false, strcat(strcat("Setting receiver_val_", channel), "... "));
          if(rc_receiver.setReceiver_val(channel.toInt(), value_01.toInt(), value_02.toInt())){
            cmd.printMsg(true, "done!");
          } else {
            //error - value(s) invalid!!!
            cmd.printMsg(true, "failed!");
            cmd.printMsg(true, "Variable could not be set -> invalid value(s)?");
          }

        } else if(sdcard.getSectionFromText(fileContentLines[i], 2, '#') == "receiver_arm_duration"){

          cmd.printMsg(false, "receiver_arm_duration: ");
          String value = sdcard.getSectionFromText(fileContentLines[i], 3, '#');

          //cmd.printMsg(0, true, "ad");
          //delay(500);
          Serial.println("TEST");

          cmd.printMsg(false, "Setting receiver_arm_duration... ");
          if(rc_receiver.setReceiver_arm_duration(value.toInt())){
            cmd.printMsg(true, "done!");
          } else {
            //error - value(s) invalid!!!
            cmd.printMsg(true, "failed!");
            cmd.printMsg(true, "Variable could not be set -> invalid value(s)?");
          }

        }
      }

    }

  }
  else {
    cmd.printMsg(true, "failed!");
    cmd.printMsg(true, "Failed to initialize SDcard!");
    cmd.printMsg(true, "Please insert SD-card and restart Arduino [or press 'O' to continue]");
    while(cmd.readCmd() != 'O') ;

    cmd.printMsg(true, "Variables couldn't be loaded!");
    cmd.printMsg(true, "Variables must be initialized manually!");
  }
}
```

---

If I forgot something - just tell me, I'll post it!

I'm thankful for any help!

Greetings Andreas

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post the code here .link seems terrible

Comment: Hello! I'm new to stackoverflow, please forgive me those mistakes! I've added the two methods.